# Model attribute value is not passed to input type text in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to set model attribute(entryNumber) value to input type text in Thymeleaf. But input value is always empty though the entryNumber value is present.

[Empty Entry Number field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CWGC.png)

Please see my *AllocationController*, *LedgerDto* and *receive-allocation.html* files.

**AllocationController**

```
/**
 * This method allows to enter receive allocation details.
 */
@GetMapping("/admin/receive-allocation")
public String receiveAllocation(final ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("entryNumber", allocationService.getLedgerEntryNumber());
    model.addAttribute("votes", allocationService.getAllVotes());
    model.addAttribute("divisions", userService.getAllDivisions());
    return "receive-allocation";
}
```

When I'm debugging the application, entryNumber is present in the ModelMap. Refer the below image.

[entryNumber is present in the ModelMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFEjI.png)

**LedgerDto**

```
public class LedgerDto {

@NotEmpty
private String voteNumber;
@NotEmpty
private String division;
@NotEmpty
private String entryNumber;

public String getVoteNumber() {
    return voteNumber;
}

public void setVoteNumber(String voteNumber) {
    this.voteNumber = voteNumber;
}

public String getDivision() {
    return division;
}

public void setDivision(String division) {
    this.division = division;
}

public String getEntryNumber() {
    return entryNumber;
}

public void setEntryNumber(String entryNumber) {
    this.entryNumber = entryNumber;
}
```

**receive-allocation.html**

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/receive-allocation}"
                                    th:object="${ledgerDto}" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-md-2"
                                            th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('entryNumber')}? 'has-error':''">
                                            <label for="inputEntryNumber">Entry Number</label> <input
                                                type="text" class="form-control"
                                                th:field="*{entryNumber}">
                                            <p class="error-message"
                                                th:each="error: ${#fields.errors('entryNumber')}"
                                                th:text="${error}">Validation error</p>
                                        </div>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use th:field when you want to prefill your form with values from your model attribute. In this case you have th:with in combination th:value

```
<form name='form' action="#" th:action="@{/internal/user/account/datachange}" method='POST' th:object="${userDTO}">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" th:with="name=*{name}" th:value="${user.name}" required></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```